# Select with multiple column creation results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables [user] and [userrights]

[user]

```
id      name
1       test1
2       test2
```

[usergroups]

```
id      name
1       member
1       admin
1       18
2       new
2       16
```

And I wanted to have this results

```
id      name        group1      group2      group3
1       test1       member      admin       18
2       test2       new         18          null
```

I tried this but I think it is the wrong way

```
SELECT *,IF(rightname = 'Member', 'Member', NULL) as status
FROM user,userrights 
where user.iduser = userrights.iduser
```

with this I get these results

```
id      name        rights      member
1       test1       member      member
1       test1       admin       null
1       test1       18          null
```

i also tried this

```
     SELECT user.iduser,GROUP_CONCAT(rightname) as groups FROM user,userrights where user.iduser = userrights.iduser GROUP BY iduser;
```

so i get a much better result

```
id      groups
1       member,admin,18
2       new,16
```

but i wanted to have for each group a new column

Comment: Can a user only be part of 3 groups maximum? Or you could join the two tables on the id and use that data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Comment: the ammount of the groups are not limmited, i think i found something usefull for me. with group_concat i just have only one column but its ok for the moment. pls tell me if someone have a better idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want separate columns, the simplest approach might be parsing the `group_concat()`:

```
select u.id, u.name,
       substring_index(group_concat(ur.rightname order by ur.rightname), ',', 1) as right1,
       substring_index( substring_index(group_concat(ur.rightname order by ur.rightname), ',', 2), ',', -1) as right2,
       substring_index( substring_index(group_concat(ur.rightname order by ur.rightname), ',', 3), ',', -1) as right3
from user u join
     userrights ur
     on u.iduser = ur.iduser 
group by u.id, u.name;
```

Notice that I also fixed your archaic join syntax and added table aliases.

Comment: thanks for your answer, so when i have 15 groups i need to make 15 substrings?

Comment: @Kim . . . That is one solution.  Usually, concatenating them using `group_concat()` is sufficient.